# Atmel ARM, USB, and an SD Card as a MSD?

Tags: usb, arm, atmel, usb-device, sd

I'm currently trying to run the SAM L21 as both a CDC and an MSD over USB. Thankfully there is example code here to get me started. I can move files into the on-board ram just like any other storage device. I can also send and receive data from a PC through a virtual COM Port created by the CDC code.

However, this is not the full implementation I have planned. I need to use a fat32 formatted SD card to save collected data. Usually one would connect an SD card to an MCU via SPI. However, I'm not sure that will work with my setup.

Can my MCU be made to write data over SPI into a fat formatted SD card? If this is possible, will the computer still recognize the SD card as formatted and usable?

If this is not possible with SPI, does anyone have experience integrating full SDC compatibility into an MCU? Links to documents or example code would be fantastic!

The end result will be a single usb connection that can sends and receive communication/data, as well as allow a user access to a formatted SD card for direct access to all data collected.

Comment: As long as you implement the filesystem on the MCU, sure.

Comment: You wouldn't typically have the MCU doing filesystem access at the same time as exposing the card to a PC over USB MSD. You're going to end up with filesystem errors that way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So if I can find or create code to have the MCU write over SPI in this format, it could work?

Comment: "In this format" involves a lot more than just writing, but yes. And don't allow direct access to the card from the host; consider using something like MTP instead.

Comment: @brhans The inteneded application is to have all data transmitted from ram to the PC over the CDC serial port, and also save all that data on-board at the same time. The user will not access the MSD until all data collection is complete.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Allowing access to the host is the whole reason I'm doing this. It removes the need to manually remove the SD card. I alos have googled the format and see that it is very detailed in all the data that must be included with any file you want to create.

Comment: If you want to do that, you have to have a huge mode switch - a FAT filesystem can only be used by one computer at a time, which is either the USB host *proxied through* the MCU, or the MCU itself.  But you can't expose the volume as both MSD and also access it from the MCU at the same time!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you saying it will not work, or that I should be careful because a user accessing the files while they are being written to will break things?

Comment: You have to assume it will not work unless both computers treat the filesystem as read-only.  If either one of them can write to it, it is not obligated to immediately flush its changes in entirety, so even if the other one is only trying to read it can read a self-inconsistent state.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could not I create the condition where if the host wants to access data, it will be refused if the data is being edited by the MCU and vice versa.

Comment: No, because you cannot know when that situation exists, unless you have decided that you will prohibit any changes whatsoever.  Even if it hasn't written anything yet, it could have uncommitted writes that *will* happen, and you can't be sure that any writes that do happen are yet sufficient to establish a self-consistent state.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I won't claim to understand, but I will take your word for it. I'll just have users manually remove the SD card if they need the files. It shouldn't be necessary, since this is more of a backup.

Comment: Most devices that want to do what you do have an explicit mode switch, where the SD card is accessible to internal functionality and USB mass storage is unavailable, vs when that is blogged and the only thing that can access it is the code that proxies to it from USB mass storage.  But obviously not implementing mass storage is simplest.  You do need a way to stop internal access before they remove the card or shut off power though.