# Disable USB class in a composite device

Tags: usb, atmel, usb-device

On my Atmel SAM4E-EK I have a USB composite device setup (MSC + CDC over USB), hooked up to a Windows 7 PC. Sometimes I want to disable the MSC and let the CDC class be, is this at all possible given the USB 2.0 specification?

I imagine a solution to my problem would be to discard all the MSC USB packets in conjunction with a forced enumeration (by the host but issued from the device).

This situation is similiar to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241206/atmel-arm-usb-and-an-sd-card-as-a-msd?rq=1) as I have a FATFS filesystem on the SD card which gets exposed to the PC over USB MSC and I want to have some kind of mutex over the filesystem so that it does not get corrupted from simultaneous accesses.

Answer (score 1):

You could pretend that you have a removable disk, and that the user ejected it.

Alternatively, remove all MSC descriptors, and force re-enumeration (disconnect the D+ pullup resistor to simulate unplugging the entire USB device).

Comment: I tried this approach and it kind of works. The problem is that I want the CDC part of my USB connection intact.